# Form field not clearing by Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Ok I create an ajax form by following a tutorial. Everything is working fine. But my form fields are not clearing after submission. I searched here & found some solution, but not working for me. I've tried:

```
number 1: $('form#contactform input[type="text"],texatrea, select').val('');

number 2: $("#name").val("");
$("#email").val("");
$("#phone").val("");

number 3:  $('#contactform')[0].reset();
```

but this solutions are not working for me.

My html:

```
    <div id="form-messages"></div>
    <form method="post" action="mailer.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
        <fieldset>


                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- Name -->
                <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" placeholder="Name" value="" />
                </div>


                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- Email -->
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" placeholder="Email" value="" />
                </div>


                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- Phone -->
                <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30" placeholder="Phone" value="" />
                </div>


                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                <!-- Send button -->
                <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Send message" />
                </div>


        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

My js:

```
$(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#contactform');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formMessages).addClass('success');

            // Clear the form.
            $('form#contactform input[type="text"],texatrea, select').val('');

            // Set the message text.
            $(formMessages).text(response);


        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
            $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
            $(formMessages).addClass('error');

            // Set the message text.
            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

& My Php

```
<?php

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $phone = strip_tags(trim($_POST["phone"]));
                $phone = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$phone);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($phone) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "friday@imransdesign.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n";
        $email_content .= "Phone: $phone\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
            $_POST=array();
        } else {            
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

What should I do?
live example: http://imransdesign.com/ajax-form/

Comment: Two things i see: 1. from `$(form)` use `form`; 2. from `$(formMessages)` use `formMessages`. Explanation: `form` and `formMessages` are already jQuery objects. Also `texatrea` is a typo.

Comment: number 1: $('#contactform input[type="text"]').val('');

Comment: I'm not using any textarea, so I can remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector for number 1 is wrong. It should be:

```
$('#contactform').find('input[type="text"], texatrea, select').val('');
```

I don't know about number 2 and number 3. May be you have duplicate IDs in your page ... let me take a look. **Your IDs are good.** Something else must be going on.

I tested number two and three in the dev tools console on your page and they work fine:

```
$('#contactform')[0].reset(); //cleared the whole form

$('#name').val(''); // Cleared the name field.
```

**There seems to be a problem with your server. It's returning a *400/404* --- fail and since you do not clear your form in the `.fail` callback, your form would not be cleared. The `.done` callback is not being called:**

```
mailer.php  POST 400 text/html jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4 279 B 378 ms   
mailer.php  POST 400 text/html jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4 279 B 339 ms   
mailer.php  POST 404 text/html jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4 256 B 343 ms
```

Somehow the server returns `Thank You! Your message has been sent.` which is output by the following part in `.fail()`:

```
if (data.responseText !== '') {
   $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
} else {
```

Comment: I've tried with another server, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Just so we're clear that jQuery/JS is not the problem you can put `number 3` - my preferred - in the `.fail()` callback and your form should clear. As long as the server is not returning a `HTTP 200` the `.done()` callback will not be fired. Quite likely your server is not configured properly .... check the logs.

Comment: already tried it, but same result. it is not working. also removed "$(formMessages).text(data.responseText);" this part from .done function, but no result either

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity, can you put `form[0].reset();` right after `$(formMessages).text(data.responseText);` in the `.fail` callback on your page and let me know.

Comment: yes indeed, finally it worked!!!! you just found the solution. but didn't understand it properly. because that code is in the fail function.

another thing, if I can remove the success message after 2/3 second, that would be great. any suggestion?

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { formMessages.empty(); },3000);` would remove the message after 3 seconds. But you may need to `declare` `formMessages` right above `$(function() {..` with `var formMessages` and then just assign it a value inside DOM ready with `formMessages = $('#form-messages');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56782/discussion-between-aohor-arsalan-and-user3558931).

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
.done(function(response) { 
    ...
    contactform.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this to clear all input fields inside form tag use this

```
$("#formid").find('input, textarea').not(":submit").val('');
```

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/WfV85/4/) will clear all the input fields and textarea inside the form tag on submitting .. change it as you want ..its just example

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#contactform fieldset div input').val('');
```

instead of

```
$('form#contactform input[type="text"],texatrea, select').val('');
```